# Redis: Move random member from one set to another atomically

Tags: redis

SRANDMEMBER returns a random member from a Set.
SPOP removes a random member from a Set.
SMOVE moves a specified member from one Set to another.

How do I move a random member from one Set to another in a single shot?
I did not want to fire a SRANDMEMBER, wait for its result and then call SMOVE.

I tried to use a EVAL script, but it cannot be used with SRANDMEMBER, issuing a "Write commands not allowed after non deterministic commands".

The operation must be O(1) and atomic.

Answer (score 2):

## Pre Redis v3.2

Redis protects against random writes inside Lua scripts so that replication will not be broken (scripts are evaluated on the slaves as well). That said, here's a pseudo-random solution:

```
local t = redis.call("SMEMBERS", KEYS[1])
local n = redis.call("SCARD", KEYS[1])
local r = math.random(1, n+1)
redis.call("SMOVE", KEYS[1], KEYS[2], t[r])
return t[r]
```

Notes:

1. Pseudo-random - Redis makes sure that the call to random is actually deterministic
2. Set sizes - since the all of set's members are fetched, you should be careful not to run it on biggish sets.

## v3.2 and greater

As of 3.2, you can be more random by calling `redis.replicate_commands()` a priori.

Comment: I need a O(1) atomic solution.

Comment: Bummer ;) In that case, short of forking Redis and adding a new command to it, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: +1 Itamar's solution is generally the correct way to do this w/ redis as a constant time operation but I wouldn't use math.random - just fold the redis ops into the single lua action you want (SRAND and SMOVE for example) to use redis' lua script to call the operations you described. The lua script is executed remotely and the execution time will be O(1)+O(1)=O(1) and the operation is 100% atomic. using lua will satisfy your conditions. I've had to solve race conditions w/ lua

Comment: @JasonG - very true, although that wasn't possible to do prior to v3.2 as it would have failed due to SRAND's non-determinism.

Comment: oh I didn't notice I was being a necromancer. Thanks for the update.

Comment: On the contrary, thank you for reminding me about this ;)

Comment: If lua scripts run atomically, what would be the pros/cons of using SRANDMEMBER+SMOVE vs SPOP+SADD ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just writing out the solution (for redis v3.2+ implied by Itamar Haber's answer. It's for those (like me!) who wish to copy-paste something working instead of actually learning lua :)

```
        redis.replicate_commands()  -- needed since we call SRANDMEMBER below
        local value = redis.call('SRANDMEMBER', KEYS[1])
        if value then
            redis.call('SMOVE', KEYS[1], KEYS[2], value)
        end
        return value
```

In my case I'm using pyredis, so I wrote this function:

```
def redis_smoverand(redis):
    """Register our smoverand() script on the given redis instance.

    smoverand() selects a random member from a set, moves it to another set atomically, and returns
    it. Usage:
    redis_smoverand(redis)('source_set', 'dest_set')

    The script is cached the first time this function is called."""

    if not getattr(redis, '_smoverand', None):
        lua = """
            redis.replicate_commands()  -- needed since we call SRANDMEMBER below
            local value = redis.call('SRANDMEMBER', KEYS[1])
            if value then
                redis.call('SMOVE', KEYS[1], KEYS[2], value)
            end
            return value
        """

        redis._smoverand = redis.register_script(lua)

    return lambda k1, k2: redis._smoverand(keys=(k1, k2), args=())
```